# PHP/Mysqli(phpmyadmin) Tento inserir no banco de dados, mas nao aparece erro

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli, phpmyadmin

Bom galera, estou precisando de ajuda com o seguinte: pretendo inserir 3 informações simples no banco de dados, nome do produto, preço e imagem. Fora do form abri uma tag pra mostrar a saída, porem só mostra o nome! e no banco de dados não aparecem registros novos, apenas os que eu adicionei diretamente no via comandos SQL. eis aqui o código:

```html
<?php 
include('config.php');
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="author" content="Publio Elon">
        <meta name="description" content="Curso de HTML5 e CSS3">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=yes">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <title>Title of the document</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form method="POST" action="">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="produto">Produto</label>
                <input type="text" name="p_name" class="form-control" id="produto" aria-describedby="cadProduto" placeholder="Nome do Produto">
                <small>Lembre-se de capitalizar a Primeira letra do nome do produto</small>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="preço">Preço do Produto</label>
                <input type="text" name="image"class="form-control" id="preço" placeholder="Preço">
                <small>Preço do produto deve ser dado apenas em números e ponto.</small>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="preço">Imagem do produto</label>
                <input type="text" name="price" class="form-control" id="preço" placeholder="Nome da Imagem">
                <small>Exemplo: teste.jpg ou teste.png verificar a extensão das imagens.</small>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Cadastrar</button>
        </form>
       <?php 
       
            function test_input($data) {
            $data = trim($data);
            $data = stripslashes($data);
            $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
            return $data;
        }       
        $p_nameErr = $priceErr = $imgErr ="";
        $p_name = $price = $image ="";
        $txtGet = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, FILTER_DEFAULT);
        if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
            if (empty($txtGet["p_name"])) {
                $p_nameErr = "Nome do produto esta vazio";
            } else {
                $p_name = test_input($txtGet["p_name"]);
                if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z]*$/", $p_name)) {
                    $p_name = "Apenas letras e espaço permitido";
                }
            }
        }
        
        
        echo "<h2>Sáida</h2>";
        echo "$p_name";
        echo "<br>";
        echo "$image";
        echo "<br>";
        echo "$price";
        echo "<br>";
        
        
        if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
        $sql = "INSERT INTO products(p_name, image, price) values('$p_name', '$image', '$price')";
        $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
        }
        echo "Produto cadastrado com sucesso!!";
        ?>

        
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>   
    </body>
    </html>
```

config.php

```
<?php
session_start();
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "admin");
mysqli_select_db($link, "loja");
?>
```

Comment: Se entendi bem, as variáveis que você exibe só recebem uma string vazia, mas nunca os valores do formulário, então não tem o que mostrar mesmo; e seu registro no banco não acontece porque nunca é satisfeita a condição do seu *If*. Deixo como dever de casa descobrir o porquê.

Comment: percebi onde esta o problema, comecei a passar o parametro pra capturar apenas o nome, e o regex não esta adequado, mas uma coisa que me deixa confuso, se ele só recebe strings vazia, pq ele nao adiciona assim mesmo os espaços em branco no BD?

Comment: Depois que passei os parametros e re-escrevi as expressões regulares sem preguiça, consegui corrigir todos os erros, obrigado mesmo, era o que você disse!

Answer (score -1):

Gostaria de agradecer ao Anderson Carlos Woss pela ajuda, eis aqui o código corrigido, caso alguém se encontre na mesma dificuldade ou esteja passando por aqui em busca de aprendizagem:

```html
<?php 
include('config.php');
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="author" content="Publio Elon">
        <meta name="description" content="Curso de HTML5 e CSS3">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=yes">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <title>Title of the document</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form method="POST" action="">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="produto">Produto</label>
                <input type="text" name="p_name" class="form-control" id="produto" aria-describedby="cadProduto" placeholder="Nome do Produto">
                <small>Lembre-se de capitalizar a Primeira letra do nome do produto</small>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="preço">Preço do Produto</label>
                <input type="text" name="image"class="form-control" id="preço" placeholder="Preço">
                <small>Preço do produto deve ser dado apenas em números e ponto.</small>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="preço">Imagem do produto</label>
                <input type="text" name="price" class="form-control" id="preço" placeholder="Nome da Imagem">
                <small>Exemplo: teste.jpg ou teste.png verificar a extensão das imagens.</small>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Cadastrar</button>
        </form>
       <?php 
       
            function test_input($data) {
            $data = trim($data);
            $data = stripslashes($data);
            $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
            return $data;
        }       
        $p_nameErr = $priceErr = $imgErr ="";
        $p_name = $price = $image ="";
        $txtGet = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, FILTER_DEFAULT);
        if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
            if (empty($txtGet["p_name"])) {
                $p_nameErr = "Nome do produto esta vazio";
            } else {
                $p_name = test_input($txtGet["p_name"]);
                if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]{1,32}$/", $p_name)) {
                    $p_nameErr = "Apenas letras e espaço permitido";
                }
            }
               if (empty($txtGet["price"])) {
                $price = "Preço do produto esta vázio!";
            } else {
                $price = test_input($txtGet["price"]);
                if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.$/", $p_name)) {
                    $priceErr = "O valor decimal da moeda deve ser separada por .";
                }
            }
                if(empty($txtGet["image"])) {
                $image = "Nome do arquivo de imagem esta vázio!";
            } else {
                $image = test_input($txtGet["image"]);
                if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9]$/", $image)) {
                    $imageErr = "o nome do arquivo deve separar o formato por .";
                }
            }
        }
        
        
        echo "<h2>Sáida</h2>";
        echo "$p_name";
        echo "<br>";
        echo "$image";
        echo "<br>";
        echo "$price";
        echo "<br>";
        
        
        if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
        $sql = "INSERT INTO products(p_name, image, price) values('$p_name', '$image', '$price')";
        $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
        }
        echo "Produto cadastrado com sucesso!!";
        ?>

        
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>   
    </body>
    </html>
```